# AUTO_INCREMENT & NOT NULL are not necessary after PRIMARY KEY (alone it's sufficient)?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, phpmyadmin, android-sqlite

I <del>know</del> ***Think*** that PRIMARY KEYs have to be <s>AUTO_INCREMENT</s> & NOT NULL ,,, but do i have to define them myself?

P.S.: is the answer affected by the DBMS I'm using ?!

#### Edited !

- **sorry I wasn't fully aware of this** => "AUTO_INCREMENT does mean it has to be UNIQUE but it's not the other way around!".
- Entity integrity constraint => No primary key value can be null.
- A PRIMARY KEY constraint => automatically has a UNIQUE constraint defined on it.

Comment: in mysql what you said is not true (first 9 words). What you ought to do is to read the manual pages on them for mysql and sqlite. We are not here to write a paragraph on each concept.

Comment: @Drew **Thanks for pointing out my mistake !** ,,, sorry if I annoyed u or anyone else ,,, but I didn't ask for a paragraph ,,, I just wanted someone to confirm my thinking or correct it ,, that's all ,, i'm a student and some concepts are still new to me,, I'm trying to ask to clarify things to myself,, and that's what stackOverflow is for, right?!

Comment: I am not annoyed. Just don't understand what the purpose of this question is for or why you have it tagged the way you do.

Comment: i'm new to DB world ,,, and i'm trying to make a project to get a better understanding of it ,, the Tags I chose r related to what i'm using ,,, I'm making an android app which stores static data using (SQLite, android-sqlite ) and if any dynamic changes happened I want to store it on a DB on my pc apache server (MySQL, phpmyadmin) ,, hence I chose those tags :D

Comment: It is hard to answer questions when 2 database engines are being used and generalities or erroneous comments are made like in yours above "AUTO_INCREMENT does mean it has to be UNIQUE... ". Please see http://pastebin.com/XAgC6BHP for mysql, note that debunks that theory, and try to have just 1 question on a question to focus on a narrow issue. As opposed to glomming both db engines into one question, without a real narrow question, and mis-characterize things in general. I say this as constructive criticism to help you, not to be a smart arse. Cheers

Comment: Thanks Drew :D i'll take ur advice into account for next times ^_^ ,,, sorry another Q ,, i didn't get it //*key(id) -- note this is not unique*// ,, i noticed that 33 & 44 took the same id so it's not unique ,,, But what does KEY mean here ?

Comment: `key` is a synonym for `index` for those of us lazy at heart

Answer (score 0):

Primary key doesn't have to be auto_increment (or some equivalent in other engines).

It doesn't have to be defined as NOT NULL either.

The PRIMARY INDEX enforces the NOT NULL check and will cause the INSERT to fail in case you try inserting NULL value. Unless the engine supports inserting NULL which I already saw too, but that's very non-standard.

Comment: great,, thank u! ,, aslo It doesn't have to be defined as UNIQUE, right !